# Gamma Matrices in Four dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\gamma^0$, $\gamma^1$, $\gamma^2$ and $\gamma^3$ be the Gamma matrices in four dimensions. My question is, how do I convince myself that these four matrices generate the set of 4-by-4 matrices over a field $K$ of characteristic not equal to 2?

Thanks!

Comment: They do not. It is spanned by their exterior products, i.e. $\{\gamma^i\}_{i=0}^3$, $\{\gamma^i \gamma^j\}_{0 \leqslant i < j \leqslant 3}$, $\{\gamma^i \gamma^j \gamma^k\}_{0 \leqslant i < j <k \leqslant 3}$ and $\gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3$.

Comment: Hmm, I meant "generate" not "span". Sorry bout that.